# Microsoft Access 2007 Query Data Type Mismatch error

Tags: ms-access

Using MS Access 2007, I'm trying to use a query as a 'lookup' to join together two tables to show rows where a common value exists in both of the joined tables (I'm thinking the Access version of Excels VLOOKUP function). Of the 10 queries I've run, 3 return the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." despite all the tables being very similar in terms of content and 1 common table being joined to each of the 10 tables in turn.

After deleting the 3 tables causing errors and starting from scratch, 1 of the tables works without error, the other 2 still have this error.

I haven't used MS Access much, so am at a loss as to what could be causing this error. After much time researching, I found this information http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175258 saying a DateTime field could be causing the error. None of my fields are DateTime, they're all Text.

Many thanks, in advance, for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried changing the datatype to `Date/Time` from `Text`? If so, does the error still occur?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've now solved the problem. Turns out 1 of the lookup fields in each table contained an error, which caused the whole query to error.

Comment: Ahh i see. I'm happy that you've resolved it!